# Create a virtual hardwired router on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, networking, wired-networking

I'm aware of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/356583/use-computer-as-a-virtual-wired-router), which due to a dead link, appears to no longer answer my question. The answer, after googling around with the link keywords, pertains to allowing the host machine to act as a wireless hotspot.

In my case, the host does not have a WiFi adapter, and I do not wish to use one. I have tried to enable a "fake hotspot" through the UI, then netsh, with no luck (thinking hotspot == implicit wired router, too). I have tried setting up a switch with Hyper-V Manager, but that did not have the intended effect.

The setup: I have a number of VMs that currently work through a VirtualBox host-only network. In addition, I have a shared connection with a Raspberry Pi over a crossover connection (using an actual crossover cable, if that matters). The host is physically connected through a switch, then a router, then a modem.

I would like to create a true virtual router, have the host machine "connect" through said router, as well as all VMs, the Raspberry, and anything else I connect to the host hardware physically.

I need to be able to physically disconnect from the aforementioned network, with the virtual sub-network still operational.

In other words: Having the same effect as connecting through another external physical router. Meaning that I can also decide to spontaneously "disconnect" a machine without having to change adapter settings, turn off sharing, etc...

Again, I have no interest in wireless connectivity, and am trying to avoid using it.

I'm trying to avoid more hardware and wires cluttering up my workspace.

I would like to avoid 3rd party software as well.

Comment: You can probably do this kind of setup with another VM that you install PfSense into. Then allocate one network card specifically to it (i.e. passthrough) and do the rest internally using virtual adapters. Then your host is only able to connect to the outer network through the virtual router